# Odds Ratio of an event on vacation periods

Tags: r

I have a data set of 1500 technical incidents. Each row represents an incident. Each incident occurs on a specific date (row 1) and is associated with a specific machine (row 2). No entry will be generated without an event. This means that there are no entry on many days. On some days, there are multiple events and thus multiple entries.
My research question is: **What is the risk of an incident occurring on holidays and vacation days?** Can anyone give me a hint on the best solution using Odds Ratio?

My data set looks like this:

```
df1 <- NULL
df1$Date <- c("01.01.2018", "02.02.2018", "02.03.2019", "02.04.2019", "01.05.2020", "15.08.2020", "14.10.2020", "31.12.2021", "04.08.2021", "17.06.2021") 
df1$Date <- strptime(x = df1$Date , format = "%d.%m.%Y")
df1$machine <- c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "c", "b", "a", "a")
df1$condition <- c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2")
df1 <- data.frame(df1)
```

Thanks!

Comment: First, you need to define what constitutes holiday and vacation days.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, this is not a problem. I would add another variable with "yes/no". But now I would also need to know on how many vacation and non-vacation periods there was no incident. Then I could at least continue with a classic two by two table. Is there an easier way to do this without manually adding all 365 calendar days in the rawdata (Excel)?